# Anaconda stopping my discord.py bot to work

Tags: python, discord.py

Im new to coding and got suggested to add anaconda to my python. I uninstalled it and now i get an error when i try to run any python code. Here is the error i get:

```
& : The term 'C:/Users/NAME/anaconda3/python.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. 
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:3
+ & "C:/Users/NAME/anaconda3/python.exe" "c:/Users/NAME/Deskt ...
+   -----------------------------------------
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:/Users/LIAM/anaconda3/python.exe:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: try running just `python`

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: instead of running `C:/Users/NAME/anaconda3/python.exe`, try running `python` in cmd

Comment: Did you uninstall python?

Comment: How? Im sorry im new to coding

Comment: @programandoconro yes i tried uninstalling and reinstalling

Comment: @knosmos how do i run it in cmd?

Comment: run this command ```where python```(for windows) or ```which python```(for unix) to check which if your python path is added to environment variable. if it is already added this command will show you the path of python in your system. please update me on this.

Comment: @Aplin ```python``` command will run python in cmd.

Comment: @Manoj i get these 2 answers:

C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe
C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe

Comment: @Aplin good then python path is already added. did you run the ```python``` command as @knosmos said?

Comment: @Manoj Yes i already did

Comment: if you still didn't get what you expected try running ```python3.9```

Comment: well i didnt mention something. Im trying to code in vs code and idk how to run it from vs code into cmd

Comment: to run a python script in vscode just right click and choose ```run python file in terminal```.